# Find lattice corresponding to sublattice

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I have a question concerning Lattice and sublattice.

I need to find the lattice corresponding to a lattice of sublattice. I have pasted the whole exercice. (It is the exercice 2.12 of the book Davey & Priestley). It's the question (ii):

[image]

I guess that the number of atoms of the lattice is 4. But I have not been able to find the lattice corresponding to $Sub_0(L)$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.**
The bottom element corresponds to $\varnothing$.
Since the lattice operations are idempotent, each element alone is a sublattice;
so if $\mathrm{Sub}_0 L$ has $4$ atoms, it means that $L$ has $4$ elements.
Now, how many (up to isomorphism) lattices with four elements are there?
It's only a matter of trying those few, and only one works.

Comment: Out of 16 posets with 4 elements, only 2 are lattices: the chain and the diamand. Right?

Comment: I think I found it. If you label the 1, 2 3 4 from left to right the atoms, only 1 and 4 are not linked. So the diamand will be 3 at the top, 2 at the bottom, 1 at the left, 4 at the rigth. Right?

Comment: To your first comment, yes, and the lattice $L$ will be the diamond. I'm not sure what you mean with your second comment. Each singleton composed of each element of $L$ is an atom of $\mathrm{Sub}_0(L)$, and then you add the other subsets which are sublattices, keeping in mind this means that if both the atoms of $L$ are in the sublattice, then the sublattice is $L$ itself. That will exclude 3 subsets. All the others belong to $\mathrm{Sub}_0(L)$, ordered by inclusion.

Comment: @pierre I forgot to add your user name to my previous comment, so perhaps you were not notified. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is L:

[image]
Right? 3 et 2 are comparable (by transitivity) but not 1 and 4.